# Boolean difference between Cylinder and Torus

Tags: modifiers, objects

I want to create a mesh like this:
[image: Cylinder with a circular Dent]
using blender version 2.83.5
It should be easy to create it with a boolean difference between the cylinder and the torus, but it seems that in the defaukt position something goes wrong.
I am new to blender forums and I never reported a bug so I want to avoid to make useless noise by first asking someone else if I am doing something wrong.
I followed this sequence:

- Open a new shene and delete the default cube
- Create a cylinder and leave everything default
- Create a torus and leave everything default
- Add a booleand difference to the cylinder with the torus as a target
- Nothing happens
- Apply the boolean and hide the torus. The cylinder is still there intact
- Go into edit mode and you'll see the traces of the difference as new edges and verteces where the torus was
- I also noticed that if the torus is not perfeclty centered (i.e. moved x by 0.001) before applying the boolean, everything works as expected.

Is this a bug or I am doing something stupid?
Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices of the torus and the edges of the cylinders are overlapping, overlappings prevent the boolean to work correctly, I think it's a problem that will be soon fixed, but for the moment you need for example to scale a little bit the torus and the boolean will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Not really a direct answer, but in this case it may be easier not to use a Boolean? Create a torus...

1. Select desired loops,<kbd>V</kbd> rip those edges,
2. Hover - <kbd>L</kbd> select unwanted faces and delete
3. Select boundary edge loops, <kbd>E</kbd> extrude, right-click to drop in place
4. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> scale the extrusions up and down
5. <kbd>F</kbd> fill the top and bottom faces

[image]

Assign a Bevel modifier by angle. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, if necessary, to recalculate normals to face outwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Actually the mesh was a little more complicated than that, and I succesfully made it anyway using the boolean with a slightly (0.001) decentered torus, and moving back to center the interested verteces (those that were belonging to the torus before applying the boolean.
The point was, not to find a way to make it, but if is was a bug preventing it to work as expected.
Thanks for the suggestion anyway, to demonstrate once more that there's no single way to (skin a cat) get the result ;)

Comment: @ziomau10 That's cool.. sometimes Booleans are the best way. I always look for the modelling approach first, and only reach for the Boolean when it does the job better, or well-enough in a much better time.